# MySql date between query went wrong

Tags: php, mysql

```
select si.total 
from sales_inv si,c nf_order co 
where si.order_num=co.order_no 
and co.cnf_no='CNF001' 
and co.added_on 
between '$month1' and '$month2'
```

Here in this query i want to get the total from the table `sales_inv` where the `order_num` in sales invoice and `order_number` in `cnf_order` should be equal.

`added_on` is a timestamp which should be between `$month1` and `$month2`

`$month1` and `$month2` are variables stored with months in timestamp format

This query is not working, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Saying "This query is not working" is not sufficient. What is not working?

Comment: I meant to say that am not getting any results though i have expected data in those tables to display but am not getting any errors. the query just runs without showin any results

Comment: Are you sure month1 and month 2 are in the correct format? Does it work if you remove the last line?

Comment: @bala: did you try my query. what was the response

Comment: @dlawrence $month1 is 2011-04-01 and $month2 is 2011-09-31 is this is the problem ? if so what should be done to make it right ?

Comment: yes, i tried ur query gowri...its working but the date between is not working. it just shows all values without considering the date between

Comment: @bala : co.added_on this column is timestamp or having only date.that is storeed exactly give example value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this

```
select si.total 
from sales_inv si,c nf_order co 
where si.order_num=co.order_no 
and co.cnf_no='CNF001' 
and ( co.added_on 
between '$month1' and '$month2')
```

Edit :-

use date function

```
   select si.total 
    from sales_inv si,c nf_order co 
    where si.order_num=co.order_no 
    and co.cnf_no='CNF001' 
    and ( DATE(co.added_on) 
    between DATE('$month1') and DATE('$month2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select si.total 
from sales_inv si,c nf_order co 
where si.order_num=co.order_no 
and co.cnf_no='CNF001' 
and co.added_on 
between STR_TO_DATE('$month1', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('$month2', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Can you give me the data it prints out when you exclude the co.added_on clause?

Comment: I tried it even by entering the date value manually but its not working select si.total from sales_inv si, cnf_order co where si.order_num = co.order_no and co.cnf_no = '$res->cnf_name' and co.added_on between STR_TO_DATE('2011-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('2011-09-31 ', '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Sorry, I meant what data do you get back when you just execute this SQL query: select si.total 
from sales_inv si,c nf_order co 
where si.order_num=co.order_no 
and co.cnf_no='CNF001'

Comment: sorry am getting the date with the total                             total  added_on
12865  2011-09-16 10:21:23

Comment: Can we try this: select si.total, co.added_on 
from sales_inv si,c nf_order co 
where si.order_num=co.order_no 
and co.cnf_no='CNF001'

Comment: sorry am getting the date with the total                          total 12865           added_on 2011-09-16 10:21:23

Comment: And just to make sure added_on is a date or timestamp type? That should work fine. You could also try: co.added_on >= STR_TO_DATE('2011-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d') and co.added_on <= STR_TO_DATE('2011-09-30', '%Y-%m-%d'). It could also be due to the fact that there are only 30 days in September.